# report about vs report on

Tags: word-usage, grammar, word-choice, word-meaning

We use the word *report* with *on* or *about*. For example:

> He reported **on** man's first view from space.
>
> He reported **about** the effects of SARS.

It seems there aren't so much differences between *on* and *about*. Are there any particular differences between them?

Comment: @LucianSava, I think you are confusing the issue by referring to a different meaning of report. The OP clearly is referring to meaning 1 and you are hinting at, without explaining, meaning 2 in the Oxford Dictionary https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/report

Answer (score 1):

For *on X*, *on* is the preposition to use if X is a topic of discussion, explanation, etc.

> He reported on man's first view from space.

The topic of his entire report, or a part of it, was "man's first view from space."  This means during the entire report or a section of it, he reported on nothing but this or revelant items.

> He reported about the effects of SARS.

*The effects of SARS* might not necessarily the topic of his/her entire report or even a part of it.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is very subtle, and many native speakers won't notice it.  Not all differences in word choice are meaningful, especially when considering the many dialects of English in common use.

In your first example, the reporting is of a specific, singular event.  In your second, the reporting is of a more general subject.  If you wish to make a distinction in your own speech, that's a reasonable one to make.